# Create an android and iphone app at the same time

Tags: android, iphone, cross-platform

I've done alot of research about app developpement but i dont seems to find a consent about creating an application that work on iphone and android with one time coding.

I'd like to know if it's possible to create an application with android studio and js that work on iphone and android device without any modification?

If not, is there a software that I can use to create an application that work on both and witch language can I use? For exemple Facebook work on iphone and android, it would be strange if they had created two separate app ...

I've never created an app for iphone before so I hope I'm clear about what I asked.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: "For exemple Facebook work on iphone and android, it would be strange if they had created two separate app" -- it is very common for Android and iOS apps to be developed separately. "I'd like to know if it's possible to create an application with android studio and js that work on iphone and android device without any modification?" -- that would depend a lot on what the app is and who its target audience is.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, I didn't tought that big app would have been developped separetly because it seems to bee alot to make it without mistakes and forgot things but thanks to make me learn! And it's a simple form app based on js because that's a language that I know. I've never created an iphone app and I'm not sure where to begin. Do you have some software to recommend me?

Comment: "And it's a simple form app based on js because that's a language that I know" -- you might consider React Native.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks that seems to fit what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flutter also for application development that allows you to create app in android and IOS both at the same time.

---